# Finding X the lowest cost trees in graph

Tags: algorithm, optimization, graph, graph-algorithm

I have Graph with N nodes and edges with cost. (graph may be Complete but also can contain zero edges).

I want to find K trees in the graph (K < N) to ensure every node is visited and cost is the lowest possible.

Any recommendations what the best approach could be?

I tried to modify the problem to finding just single minimal spanning tree, but didn't succeeded.
Thank you for any hint!

**EDIT**

little detail, which can be significant. To cost is not related to crossing the edge. The cost is the price to BUILD such edge. Once edge is built, you can traverse it forward and backwards with no cost. The problem is not to "ride along all nodes", the problem is about "creating a net among all nodes". I am sorry for previous explanation

**The story**
Here is the story i have heard and trying to solve.

There is a city, without connection to electricity. Electrical company is able to connect just K houses with electricity. The other houses can be connected by dropping cables from already connected houses. But dropping this cable cost something. The goal is to choose which K houses will be connected directly to power plant and which houses will be connected with separate cables to ensure minimal cable cost and all houses coverage :)

Comment: I think this should be called "lowest-cost minimal spanning tree".  I answered it as a classic lowest-cost path problem (and got down-voted while I was re-reading the problem!)  My fault for answering too quickly.

Comment: How does the graph problem you are describing model your business problem?  For one, where does the restriction to paths apply?  Typically, utility connections are modeled with trees.

Comment: @David you are 100 right, my bad... I again edit the question

Comment: +1: The editted problem is a very interesting question [well, in my opinion at last]. Can you provide where is it from? real life app? contest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just came up with the easy solution as follows:

N - node count

C - direct connections to the grid

E - available edges

---

1, Sort all edges by cost

2, Repeat (N-C) times:

1. Take the cheapest edge available
2. Check if adding this edge will not caused circles in already added edge
3. If not, add this edge

3, That is all... You will end up with C disjoint sets of edges, connect every set to the grid

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, this is NP hard.  However, if you're willing to accept a *good* solution, you could use simulated annealing.  For example, the traveling salesman problem is NP hard, yet near-optimal solutions can be found using simulated annealing, e.g. http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26758/Simulated-Annealing-Solving-the-Travelling-Salesma

Comment: @relaxxx: That's what I figured, but it was worth a try.  Hopefully your graphs are small!

Answer (score 0):

Assume you can find a minimum spanning tree in `O(V^2)` using prim's algorithm.

For each vertex, find the minimum spanning tree with that vertex as the root.

This will be `O(V^3)` as you run the algorithm V times.

Sort these by total mass (sum of weights of their vertices) of the graph. This is `O(V^2 lg V)` which is consumed by the `O(V^3)` so essentially free in terms of order complexity.

Take the X least massive graphs - the roots of these are your "anchors" that are connected directly to the grid, as they are mostly likely to have the shortest paths. To determine which route it takes, you simply follow the path to root in each node in each tree and wire up whatever is the shortest. (This may be further optimized by sorting all paths to root and using only the shortest ones first. This will allow for optimizations on the next iterations. Finding path to root is `O(V)`. Finding it for all V X times is `O(V^2 * X)`. Because you would be doing this for every V, you're looking at `O(V^3 * X)`. This is more than your biggest complexity, but I think the average case on these will be small, even if their worst case is large).

I cannot prove that this is the optimal solution. In fact, I am certain it is not. But when you consider an electrical grid of 100,000 homes, you can not consider (with any practical application) an NP hard solution. This gives you a very good solution in O(V^3 * X), which I imagine is going to give you a solution very close to optimal.

Comment: I do not quite understand your solution. Final result should be X connected n-tuples of edges. Each tuple can belong to the different spannig tree. How can I get this solution from your suggestion?

Comment: A minimum spanning tree can be computed in `O(V^2)` using prim's algorithm. Each spanning tree will have the smallest distance to each node assuming it is the root. By letting each node be the root for a moment and calculating the minimum spanning tree that results, you can find what has the most optimal set of all paths. Could you describe (in plain terms) what other objective you might be trying to achieve? Your edit seems to indicate you're removing the cost - I simply don't understand how this is possible or what it's trying to represent.

Comment: Please, see the story in my question :)

Comment: I have reformulated my answer with a sub-optimal, but more practical solution.

Comment: thank you for your effort! your solution is nice and practical, unfortunately as you said, it will not provide the optimal results... If you are interested, please, take look at my answer

Comment: Well, honestly your solution looks almost identical to mine, except for some reason you're trying random anchors until you get it right where as I pick the roots of the smallest MSTs. This pushes your order up to `O(V^4)`, while mine is `O(V^3 lg V)` Other than that they're identical, and they both have the problem of being unproven to be optimal.

Comment: Oh so I am sorry, I probably misunderstood your solution... I going to read it again :)

Comment: I still do not thing are almost identical. I think mine may be optimal (haven't prove it though)... I think I just describe it badly, so take a look at paintings

Answer (score 0):

You are describing something like a cardinality constrained [path cover](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_cover).  It's in the Traveling Salesman/ Vehicle routing family of problems and is NP-Hard.  To create an algorithm you should ask

1. Are you only going to run it on small graphs.
2. Are you only going to run it on special cases of graphs which do have exact algorithms.
3. Can you live with a heuristic that solves the problem approximately.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your story, I think that what you call a path can be a tree, which means that we don't have to worry about Hamiltonian circuits.

Looking at the proof of correctness of Prim's algorithm at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm, consider taking a minimum spanning tree and removing the most expensive X-1 links. I think the proof there shows that the result has the same cost as the best possible answer to your problem: the only difference is that when you compare edges, you may find that the new edge join two separated components, but in this case you can maintain the number of separated components by removing an edge with cost at most that of the new edge.

So I think an answer for your problem is to take a minimum spanning tree and remove the X-1 most expensive links. This is certainly the case for X=1!

Comment: you are right, path can be tree... I edited the question... your solution is nice, but just for X=1 case

Answer (score 0):

Here is attempt at solving this...

For X=1 I can calculate minimal spanning tree (MST) with Prim's algorithm from each node (this node is the only one connected to the grid) and select the one with the lowest overall cost

For X=2 I create extra node (Power plant node) beside my graph. I connect it with random node (eg. N0) by edge with cost of 0. I am now sure I have one power plant plug right (the random node will definitely be in one of the tree, so whole tree will be connected). Now the iterative part. I take other node (eg. N1) and again connected with PP with 0 cost edge. Now I calculate MST. Then repeat this process with replacing N1 with N2, N3 ...
So I will test every pair [N0, NX]. The lowest cost MST wins.

For X>2 is it really the same as for X=2, but I have to test connect to PP every (x-1)-tuple and calculate MST

with x^2 for MST I have complexity about (N over X-1) * x^2... Pretty complex, but I think it will give me THE OPTIMAL solution

what do you think?

**edit** by random node I mean random but FIXED node

**attempt to visualize for x=2** (each description belongs to image above it)

[image]

Let this be our city, nodes A - F are houses, edges are candidates to future cables (each has some cost to build)

[image]

Just for image, this could be the solution

[image]

Let the green one be the power plant, this is how can look connection to one tree

[image]

But this different connection is really the same (connection to power plant(pp) cost the same, cables remains untouched). That is why we can set one of the nodes as fixed point of contact to the pp. We can be sure, that the node will be in one of the trees, and it does not matter where in the tree is.

[image]

So let this be our fixed situation with G as PP. Edge (B,G) with zero cost is added.

[image]

Now I am trying to connect second connection with PP (A,G, cost 0)

[image]

Now I calculate MST from the PP. Because red edges are the cheapest (the can actually have even negative cost), is it sure, that both of them will be in MST.

[image]

So when running MST I get something like this. Imagine detaching PP and two MINIMAL COST trees left. This is the best solution for A and B are the connections to PP. I store the cost and move on.

[image]

Now I do the same for B and C connections

[image]

I could get something like this, so compare cost to previous one and choose the better one.

This way I have to try all the connection pairs (B,A) (B,C) (B,D) (B,E) (B,F) and the cheapest one is the winner.

For X=3 I would just test other tuples with one fixed again. (A,B,C) (A,B,D) ... (A,C,D) ... (A,E,F)

Comment: I don't think it will work [be optimized], since you enforce connecting 2 nodes to the 'power plant', which might be worth then connecting two other nodes..

Comment: @amit they are connected by edge with zero cost, so mini MST algorithm sure use both of them in MST

Comment: if the power plant can be connected to each node with cost 0 it changes the whole picture. Is it the case? Also, when you create all these MST's, you need to 'know' which vertices to 'leave out' in each MST. I migt be missing the point of your algorithm, can you make it more formal and explain the guidelines how to prove it is optimized?

Comment: power plant can be connected to exactly X nodes. X is given on input. I will try visualize "power plant connecting" on simple diagram

Comment: @amit pseudo diagram is up :)

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like the famous Traveling Salesman problem. The problem known to be NP-hard. Take a look at the Wikipedia as your starting point: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem